# Python Keras - How to input custom image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
    from keras import *
import os
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, ZeroPadding2D
from keras import optimizers

# Collecting data:
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
training_data_dir = "train"
testing_data_dir = "test"
batch_size = 16

# prepare data augmentation configuration
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    training_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    testing_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

# Building model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer="rmsprop",
              metrics=["accuracy"])

#  Training model:
nb_epoch = 1
nb_train_samples = 2048
nb_validation_samples = 832

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        epochs=nb_epoch,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=nb_validation_samples,
        steps_per_epoch=64)
```

My code here creates a neural network for image classification based on pictures it is trained on, I have searched all over the internet but one thing I can't understand is how to input my own image file to test against the network and for it to print out the output. For example if the net was for classifying dogs and cats, I'm not sure on how to code the bit where I input a jpg/png file for a dog or a cat and the program to output which class it is. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

You call the model's `predict` method. https://keras.io/models/model/#predict

Comment: Again from the docs: x: The input data, as a Numpy array (or list of Numpy arrays if the model has multiple inputs). Check out some basic keras tutorials online, there are lots of good examples out there.

Comment: [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/basics-of-image-classification-with-keras-43779a299c8b) looks like a good one to get you started. Good luck!